# JAVA - Update .properties file

Tags: java, properties, runtime

I'm trying to update my .properties file inside my jar, but without success.
After try to do this in a thousand of different ways, I got this example here:

```
    final AbstractFileConfiguration prop = new PropertiesConfiguration("application.properties");

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty(property));

    if (prop.containsKey(property)) {
        prop.setProperty(property, value);
        prop.save();
    }
```

And this is returning for me an Exception:

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not save to URL jar:file:/home/pedepano/myjarapp.jar!/application.properties
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:464)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.save(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:377)
at com.library.core.Configs.updateSimpleProperty(Configs.java:151)
at com.print.model.business.caixa.cnab240.listmodel.AbstractCnab240ListModel.mouseClicked(AbstractCnab240ListModel.java:111)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
```

Some say that's not possible to update the .properties file in runtime, some say that is. I have wasting really too time trying to find the answer...
Is that possible?
If yes, how?
If no, what could I do instead?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write back to the *.properties* file that has been compiled into your .jar, as far as I know, this is not possible; you can however, write that properties file to an external source.

```
File f = new File("my.properties");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( f );
props.store(f, "a comment");
```

This will create the file alongside your .jar file.

If this is the route you choose, you might want to first try loading from the external file, and default to the internal one for defaults if external is not found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it. This is a good way to make it. But I'm thinking about a way to store database host, user and password information in safely. Do I have another option to store database and important information?

Comment: Use filesystem permissions - create a system user that will be the one running this service, and disallow all other users and groups from accessing the directory you store your data. Writing it into the _.jar_ file is in no way safer, as a _.jar_ is essentially just a _.zip_ file. I can easily decompress it and view the contents of the properties file. If you do your permission correctly, you will not have an issue - this is how I do it, and how it is done in many enterprise solutions.

Comment: Your other option is using an Encryption / Decryption library to encrypt on save, and decrypt on load.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll make an Encryption/Decryption library. Guess this way is easy and quick too, even I make my program in a Linux machine, but this will run in Windows, so the permissions may not be an easy and effective way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     try {      
             String propertiesFilePath = ("your file path");
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath);
             properties.load(fis);

             properties.setProperty("key","value");

             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(propertiesFilePath);
             properties.store(fos,null);
             System.out.println("SUCCESS");
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println("FAILED");
     }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)